# make div css width 1366px height 768px fit the parent div

Tags: html, css, height, width, pixel

I have an code

```
<div class="parent">
     <div class ="child"></div>
</div>
```

parent div have class col-lg-12

I want make "child" div have width 1366px and height 768px but fit with the "parent" div, how to do it?.

so I don't need to scroll the screen anymore. I hope you guys can help.

Thanks

Comment: You can use:  `.child {width: 1366px; height: 768px; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;}`

Answer (score 0):

See if this is what you've looking for.

```css
.parent{
  width: 100%;
}
.child{
  width: 1366px;
  height: 768px;
  max-width:100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  background-color:red;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
     <div class ="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you , hopefully you are looking for screen adjustment to your child div , so use viewport unit (vw and vh).

```
.parent{  width: 100%; }
.child {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```